# how do i update data in access database using c# 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
        OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\SummerJob\DataBase.accdb");
        string cmdtxt = "UPDATE Students SET S_Name = ?, S_Surname = ?, S_E-Mail = ? WHERE ID = ?";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdtxt, vcon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("S_Name", EditName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("S_Surname", editSurname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("S_E-Mail", editMail.Text);
        vcon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        vcon.Close();
```

//i use this code but it says syntax error in update statement

Answer (score 1):

Where is the last parameter ???

```
ID=?
```

Not sure, but I will bet that without that parameter your query doesn't look right to the parser.

Comment: ID is row to edit right ? I am new i don't now that much i just did this with tutorial.

Comment: if (StudentList.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.index = StudentList.SelectedIndices[0];
                }

Comment: can i use index as ID if i use listview to show database members

Comment: I don't think so, perhaps for some items you get the right value, but you should refer to the correct ID on the database table. When you load your data you need to store somewhere this info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass ID? via SqlParameter like this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", Id.Text);

Also make sure that the parameters are added in the same order they occur

Comment: waht does ID parameter represent ? it's row to edit or what ?

Comment: ID is Id column of the Students Table, so each row in the students table have unique Id this is a primary key

Comment: for example i want to edit the row i select in listview and i want to pass them value through texboxes whichs names are editname editsurname and editmail. how should i do that what should be the code and then store updated data back in the database name of listview os studenList

Comment: @DitoQarcidze you above code is correct all you have to do is pass the ID in sqlparameter